# Adding more than one localStorage Array to an normal Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, local-storage

Hello guys I have a question. I have made a calendar and everything works, but the last requirement is to add dates through `localStorage`.

So my question: how can I add more dates without overwriting the first one?
I was thinking about getting the data out, add the new `testObject`, and put it back to `localStorage`. The only thing is I have no clue how to do it.

I hope someone can help. ( I am quite a beginner )

So in short, I want to put more than one array into the `events`-array through `localStorage`.

---

This is my code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" >
    testObject = ["Y", prompt("maand"), prompt("dag"), "2000", prompt("test"), prompt("test")]
    retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObject');

    // Put the object into storage
    localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject))



events = new Array(
          JSON.parse(retrievedObject),
        ["Y",   "1",    "1",    "2000",     "Nieuw jaars dag",  "De eerste dag van het nieuw Jaar"],
        ["Y",   "7",    "3",    "2000",     "Mijn verjaardag", "beste dag van het jaar"],
        ["Y",   "17",   "10",   "2000",     "Inleverdag",   "Ergste dag van het jaar."]
    );
</script>
```

Edit : after I add 2 arrays it should Work like this But the upper 2 values should be retrieved form local storage and if I add another one it should be 3 arrays in the local storage. But the local storage overwrites itself everytime So at the moment I am only able to add 1 array

```
events = new Array(
        ["Y",   "1",    "2",    "2000",     "test", "test"],

         ["Y",  "2",    "4",    "2000",     "test2",    "test3"],
        ["Y",   "1",    "1",    "2000",     "Nieuw jaars dag",  "De eerste dag van het nieuw Jaar"],
        ["Y",   "7",    "3",    "2000",     "Mijn verjaardag", "beste dag van het jaar"],
        ["Y",   "17",   "10",   "2000",     "Inleverdag",   "Ergste dag van het jaar."]
    );
```

Comment: What do expect the value of `events` to be? Can you edit the question and output the computed value you'd like to see?

Comment: I put an edit on top what I would like to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the confusion is in your wording, Your asking how to add data to an array but the code examples you provide don't do any adding at all.

I think what your after is [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and [`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

In an effort to show and example I will make the following assumptions of what you **want** to do:

```
// Helper to easily create a new test object
function buildTestObject() {
  return [
    'Y',
    prompt('maand'),
    prompt('dag'),
    '2000',
    prompt('test'),
    prompt('test')
  ];
}

// Pull in the old value from localStorage
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObjects') || '[]';

try {
  // Turn JSON into JS Object
  retrievedObject = JSON.parse(retrievedObject);
} catch (e) {
  retrievedObject = [];
}

// Actually add a testObject to the array which will be stored in localStorage
retrievedObject.push(buildTestObject());

// Save the now mutated array of testObjects back into localStorage
localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(retrievedObject))

var events = retrievedObject.concat(
  ["Y",   "1",    "1",    "2000",     "Nieuw jaars dag",  "De eerste dag van het nieuw Jaar"],
  ["Y",   "7",    "3",    "2000",     "Mijn verjaardag", "beste dag van het jaar"],
  ["Y",   "17",   "10",   "2000",     "Inleverdag",   "Ergste dag van het jaar."]
);
```

Comment: This helps alot only one problem the events that are already in the list stopped working any idea why?

Comment: I fixed it thank you Thank you !. Because of you I completed the course on school